# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slider'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, runtime-error

When navigating and refreshing the page via AJAX I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slider'`

Strange this is that if you go directly to the page the price slider function on the left bottom does work.

I read this may be because of a jQuery version conflict, so I added a test:

```
console.log("VERSION OF JQUERY:"+jQuery().jquery);
```

That returns `1.10.2`

I would think just the latest version is available.

I tried adding `noConflict()`, before this line:

```
$("#slider_pricefilter").slider({
```

But then a whole chain of other errors is triggered, consisting of `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object` type errors throughout all my jQuery code.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If you look at `$("#slider_pricefilter")` as a watch expression in your preferred devtools, the object has no function `slider`. Try re-downloading your jQuery-UI, as you're using a custom build and something may have gone wrong. Also I tried the slider on `www.toptrouwen.nl/trouwshoptest` and it seemed buggy!

Comment: I now pointed my jQuery ui script to the CDN of jQuery ui: 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js'. Also I fixed the slider on 'trouwshoptest' to have no negative start value. Now I get the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined

Comment: Where is that error appearing? `addClass` is a method of jQuery, so when the browser is saying `undefined`, it means your code is calling the method before jQuery is initialised.

Comment: I had a quick look at your source code, and you appear to be calling jQuery twice. `jquery 1.8.3.min.js` from `apis.google.com` and `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` from your own server. This may cause problems

Comment: @Adam,thanks.How did you find out which jQuery versions are loaded? (for my future reference).The only reference I see to apis.google.com is on this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>`,I removed that line locally,but still get the `addClass` error.How is it possible that the addClass method is called before jQuery is loaded when I reference jQuery at the top of my page?`<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: You already know how to find the version being loaded, "`console.log("VERSION OF JQUERY:"+jQuery().jquery);`". Without knowing where you're getting the error message, there's not much more I can do to help

Comment: I just searched for jquery in the html. Saw that there were 2 versions of jquery being loaded, that's all. Which file contains the code that creates the slider? - Nvm, I've found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found your problem.

You're using strings as the min/max values of the slider.

http://www.toptrouwen.nl/trouwshoptest - Line 462/463. Do `parseFloat($("#pricemin").attr('data-message'))` etc. to ensure it gets passed as a integer value so it doesn't break jQuery-UI

Comment: You sir...rock ;) Thanks!